# What are the best ways to convey the idea of getting to a destination?

Tags: meaning, expressions

To express `to get to` or `to reach` a destination I see a few options:

到達{とうたつ}する

達{たっ}する

到着{とうちゃく}する

届{とど}く

And variations.

I have found 到達する as having clear examples with physical destinations (e.g. 公園に到達する - get to the park), but the rest seem to be used, for the most part, with figurative ideas/destinations (e.g. to reach a point, to reach a level of expertise).

What are the nuances of each and how would I best express getting to a destination?

Comment: You may want to add 着く as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the typical examples:

> - 待ち合わせ場所の公園に[到着した／着いた]。
> - ついにエベレストの頂上に到達した。
> - 彼の大声は公園まで[達した／届いた]。
> - 手紙が家に[届いた／到着した／着いた]。

- 到着する and 着く are the most common and generic words for "to arrive". The former is a bit more formal and stiff, but the difference is not very large.
- 到達する is to reach somewhere, but usually after some effort/struggle. 「公園に到達する」 sounds like the park is the goal of a marathon race. It can also be used with 考え/合意/理解/etc.
- 達する is usually used with inanimate objects like sound, pollution, water.
- 届く is more like "to be delivered" and used with inanimate objects.